# can't reference `$this` in data provider

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a test where I set up some variables in setup:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $foo;
    private $bar;

    function setUp() {
      $this->foo = "hello";
      $this->bar = "there";
    }

    private function provideStuff() {
        return [
            ["hello", $this->foo],
            ["there", $this->bar],
        ];
    }
}
```

And then I reference those vars in the `provideStuff` provider. But they are all NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The data provider is running before the `setup()` function. Can you initialise your variables in the data provider? Alternatively, maybe put the assignments in the constructor (and remember to call parent)?

Comment: This might work...I'm not comfortable with overriding the constructor here. For future visitors: it is important to call the parent's constructor as well, otherwise you will run into this issue https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/621

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `setUpBeforeClass` and static vars will solve your problem.

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private static $foo;
    private static $bar;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
      self::$foo = "hello";
      self::$bar = "there";
    }

    private function provideStuff() {
        return [
            ["hello", self::$foo],
            ["there", self::$bar],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like this doesn't run before the providers, because self::$foo etc are all NULL.

Answer (score -1):

I run into same problem while doing unit tests. I think this has to do with how tests are run, but I didn't do in depth research on the topic. Here's how I solved it:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

function setUp() {
  $data['foo'] = "hello";
  $data['bar'] = "there";
 return $data;
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @depends setUp
 */
private function provideStuff($data) {
    echo $data['foo'];
} }
```

It's defintely not the best solution but it works :).

Comment: So the result of `setUp` gets passed to providers? Just tested this and looks like it doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're trying to reinvent the `__construct` function

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   private $foo;
   private $bar;

   function __construct() {
      $this->foo = "hello";
      $this->bar = "there";
   }

   private function provideStuff() {
      return [
          ["hello", $this->foo],
          ["there", $this->bar],
      ];
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: If his objective is to assign these variables upon class creation, which is presumed with the `setUp()` function, I don't see why not.

Comment: `setUp` and `tearDown` are called around each test method, not just on object construction.

Comment: if you do this, you still need to call `parent::__construct()`.

Comment: @VladtheImpala True. I'd update my edit, but it doesn't seem to be what the author is trying to accomplish anyway ;)